# Change drawer selection on PageViewer page change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am making a book reader application. Each chapter is an entry in drawer. I am using single view pager for all chapters. 
I want to change selected index in drawer based on current chapter (current page in view pager).
Say book has 10 chapter each having 10 pages.
When user goes from page 10 to 11, selected chapter in drawer should change to 2.

Comment: what's the problem now ? post your code pls.

Comment: Assuming there is a navigation drawer reflecting Chapters as a list item , and when end page of the chapter reached you want to change the selection position in the drawer  and start the page from index zero . Am i correct?

Comment: viewPager will be continuous, consisting all 100 pages one after another.
On change selection position in drawer, viewPager current page index will change and vice versa.

Comment: use setCurrentItem() from viewpager when selected from drawer, and when page is scrolled, set drawer item seleced by getting getCurrentItem();